# At the end of my surname, do I place a comma or full stop?

Tags: commas

> My name is Selwyn Goodman. I’m a logo design specialist with over 5 years experience working with start-up brands.

Answer (score 1):

Using a comma creates a run-on sentence. You already have two complete sentences, and you can't join those with just a comma.

You can use a conjunction like *and,* probably with a comma like my second sentence above; or you can use a semicolon. That choice is stylistic: I'm not saying which one to use, just what is available.

And of course, two sentences is just fine. But don't use only a comma.

> My name is Selwyn Goodman. I’m a logo design specialist...
> My name is Selwyn Goodman, and I’m a logo design specialist...
> My name is Selwyn Goodman; I’m a logo design specialist...

Note that if your second clause is not a complete sentence — missing out the main verb, say — then a comma is fine. It may not be suitable for your current text, but it's grammatically ok.

> My name is Selwyn Goodman, a logo design specialist...

Answer (score -1):

It's a matter of choice Selwyn, but I would use a comma in that situation. If you were going to expand on your CV (for instance by giving a few examples of brands you've worked with which have gone on to become well known) then staring a second sentence at that point would be appropriate but as you have written it the two sentences express a single concept so would be better as more complex sentence.

If you use too many short sentences then the text becomes fragmented and awkward.